# ext js 4 rowediting how to add custom attributes for selenium testing id purposes in a grid

Tags: extjs, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, extjs4.1

I have an ext js grid that uses the plugin row editing. I need to write selenium test scripts and would like to assign static ids or custom attributes to the row editing form fields and update and cancel buttons.. I know how to rename button text.. but what I really need to do is add a attribute so I can reference with selenium testing.

See fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/remy/AVTrU/6/).. if someone could show me how it would be appreciated (newbie extjs).

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555--222-1234"},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
    ]
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            pluginId: 'qqrowEditingqq'
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
if (Ext.grid.RowEditor) {
        Ext.apply(Ext.grid.RowEditor.prototype, {
            saveBtnText : "Guardar",
            cancelBtnText : "Cancelar",
            errorsText : "Errores",
            dirtyText : "Debe guardar o cancelar sus cambios"
        });
    }
grid.on('beforeedit', function(e) {
    if (e.record.get('phone') == "555-111-1224")
        grid.getPlugin('qqrowEditingqq').editor.form.findField('name').disable();
    else
        grid.getPlugin('qqrowEditingqq').editor.form.findField('name').enable();
});
```

I don't want to do xpath for this.

we will be doing grids and roweditng on many pages and would like to write selenium test scripts that select the object some sort of attribute that targets one form field or button within a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class names to all the elements in the panel.

For example, add `cls: 'panel-simpsons'` to the panel, add `cls: 'header-name', tdCls: 'col-name'` to each column (not requested here by you, but I think might be useful for other tests), the the x-grid-row-editor can be located by cssselector `.panel-simpsons .x-grid-row-editor`, then you will have two buttons inside this.

Sample ExtJs code:

```javascript
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555--222-1234"},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
    ]
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    cls: 'panel-simpsons', // NEW!!!
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', cls: 'header-name', tdCls: 'col-name', editor: 'textfield'}, // NEW!!!
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1, cls: 'header-email', tdCls: 'col-email', // NEW!!!
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', cls: 'header-phone', tdCls: 'col-phone'} // NEW!!!
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            pluginId: 'qqrowEditingqq'
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
if (Ext.grid.RowEditor) {
        Ext.apply(Ext.grid.RowEditor.prototype, {
            saveBtnText : "Guardar",
            cancelBtnText : "Cancelar",
            errorsText : "Errores",
            dirtyText : "Debe guardar o cancelar sus cambios"
        });
    }
grid.on('beforeedit', function(e) {
    if (e.record.get('phone') == "555-111-1224")
        grid.getPlugin('qqrowEditingqq').editor.form.findField('name').disable();
    else
        grid.getPlugin('qqrowEditingqq').editor.form.findField('name').enable();
});
```

Now are the sample C# code for locating elements:

(Please note that locators are chained to simplify the CssSelector, start using `WebDriver.FindElement`, then `PanelSimpsons.FindElement`, then `GridRowEditor.FindElement`)

```C#
public IWebElement PanelSimpsons {
    get { return WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".panel-simpsons")); }
}

public IWebElement ColumnHeaderName {
    get { return PanelSimpsons.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".header-name")); }
}

public IList<IWebElement> ColumnName {
    get { return PanelSimpsons.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".col-name")); }
}

#region Row editor
public IWebElement GridRowEditor {
    get { return PanelSimpsons.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".x-grid-row-editor")); }
}

public IWebElement InputName {
    get { return GridRowEditor.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='name']")); }
}

public IWebElement InputEmail {
    get { return GridRowEditor.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='email']")); }
}

public IList<IWebElement> RowEditorButtons {
    get { return GridRowEditor.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.x-grid-row-editor-buttons button")); }
}

public IWebElement BtnUpdate {
    get { return RowEditorButtons[0]; }
}

public IWebElement BtnCancel {
    get { return RowEditorButtons[1]; }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed very helpful example.         When you say this "Please note that locators are chained to simplify the CssSelector, start using WebDriver.FindElement, then PanelSimpsons.FindElement, then GridRowEditor.FindElement)." Are you saying that one depends on the other and have to be executed in a certain sequence on separate lines?  Could you provide an example of how to do the chaining?  thank you again

Comment: The code I provided above is the example. Use `WebDriver.FindElement()` for `PanelSimpsons`, `ColumnHeaderName` is found by `PanelSimpsons.FindElement()` rather than `WebDriver.FindElement()`. In this case, `PanelSimpsons.FindElement()` will call that `public IWebElement PanelSimpsons {}` automatically. I'm using C# and Java should be similar, but unsure about Ruby or other languages. You can totally ignore this, just use longer css selector e.g. `.panel-simpsons .x-grid-row-editor input[name='email']` to find `InputEmail `